# Is it possible to update session attribute in tomcat session clustering?

Tags: session, tomcat, load-balancing

I need to cluster Tomcat servers(and Spring framework) for the session sharing.

For the user authority check(ex: DB CRUD), I want to set authority info in the user's session attribute.

I found some answers how to do it using session listner to manage login-ed sessions list.

I have a question here.

When Login-ed administrator changes one login-ed user's authority in DB, 
is it possible to update authority attribute in the matching user's session?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about clustering? 
You can update the session with the new attribute. You can also have the session replicated to other Tomcat nodes. 
If you expect it to change mid-session, why not check the database for the permission. That's probably less cumbersome.

Comment: @Darius X. In my clustering servers, only one(main) server can access authority DB, so checking auth info from session attribute(replicated to all server) is my idea.

Comment: If the session is replicated properly, you should be good. I have used Tomcats as peers. If the user is authenticated something goes in the session, and this is check on each request -- via a filter-type mechanism. If one Tomcat is stopped and the session migrates to a peer, the user does not have to login again. Everything remains as if nothing happened. The only time there's an issue is if something in the session does not get serialized properly.... in which case the session does not migrate over anyway=, and the user ends up with a login-page.